# Why is this plot flat?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a Dataframe which has 3 columns like:

```
Recency Frequency   Revenue
    370 14          1717.99
    382 130         144280.48
    383 20          126129.37
```

To visualize in 2d I am applying PCA transformation and get the following:

```
sklearn_pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X1 = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(df1)
X1 = X1[:, ::-1] # flip axes 
kmeans = KMeans(3, random_state=0)
labels = kmeans.fit(X1).predict(X1)
plt.scatter(X1[:, 0], X1[:, 1], c=labels, s=40, cmap='viridis');
```

[image]

The following code is for visualizing K-means clustering with data, but I am getting a flat graph.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def plot_kmeans(kmeans, X, n_clusters=4, rseed=0, ax=None):
    labels = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

    # plot the input data
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels, s=40, cmap='viridis', zorder=2)

    # plot the representation of the KMeans model
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    radii = [cdist(X[labels == i], [center]).max()
             for i, center in enumerate(centers)]
    for c, r in zip(centers, radii):
        ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(c, r, fc='#CCCCCC', lw=3, alpha=0.5, zorder=1))

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
plot_kmeans(kmeans, X1)
```

[image]

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot is not "flat", it is just the scale on the y-axis that is way too big to show the difference between your points.

If you get rid of `ax.axis('equal')` in your second code, you should get back the right limits on the y-axis (or change them using `ax.set_ylim(-5000,7000)`), but of course your circles won't be round anymore.